# free(): invalid pointer when adding string

Tags: c++

This code works ok:

```
void sendToOne(int fd, string message)
{
    message += "$";
    char* S = new char[message.length()];
    strcpy(S, message.c_str());
    write(fd, S, message.length());
}
```

But when I add small change:

```
void sendToOne(int fd, string message)
{
    string msg2 = message + "$";
    char* S = new char[msg2.length()];
    strcpy(S, msg2.c_str());
    write(fd, S, msg2.length());
}
```

I am getting: `free(): invalid pointer` error. Can you explain me why does that happen?

Comment: Why bothering with raw pointers when you have [std::string::data](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data)/[std::string::c_str](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) ?

Comment: Try `char* S = new char[msg2.length() + 1];`; and [UB](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) means anything is possible.

Comment: You could save a lot of memory allocation by making 2 calls to write, and take `message` by reference in the first place

Comment: `void sendToOne(int fd, const string & message) { write(fd, message.c_str(), message.length()); write(fd, "$", 1); }`

Answer (score 5):

Your code has a buffer overrun write in it:

```
char* S = new char[msg2.length()];
strcpy(S, msg2.c_str());
```

The first line allocates enough space for the characters in `msg2`, but the second line copies said characters (assuming no embedded `NUL`s) *and* the `NUL` byte at the end (a total of one byte more than you allocated). If you get unlucky, and there were no slack bytes at the end of the allocation, you'll often overwrite allocator metadata bytes preceding a subsequent allocation (or an entry in the free list); when the allocator tries to use them, it (if you're "lucky") tries to read invalid memory and dies immediately; if you're "unlucky", it happens to point to random memory that's available to your process, but probably not the right place, and you get progressively more and more corruption until everything explodes.

All that said, it's kind of silly to do this. Just write the `string`'s data directly:

```
string msg2 = message + "$";
write(fd, msg2.c_str(), msg2.length());
```

which also avoids the memory leak you made by using `new` without smart pointer management or a matching call to `delete[]`.

Answer (score 3):

you need extra 1 byte to hold the null character
`char* S = new char[msg2.length() + 1];`

see [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/)